# IBM IoT output node to websockets end-point

Tags: node.js, websocket, mqtt, node-red, watson-iot

In my Node-RED flow, I have wired an IBM IoT Input node to an IBM IoT Output node. I am using `mosquitto_pub` on command line to publish to WIoTP so that the Node-RED flow is started. Similarly, I am using `mqtt sub` (from [mqttjs](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js)) to subscribe to the message from the Node-RED flow. However, I am not receiving payload on my subscription terminal window.

**Publish**

```
mosquitto_pub -h orgId.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com -p 8883 -i d:orgId:dType:default -u use-token-auth -P 'authToken' --cafile messaging.pem -t iot-2/evt/data/fmt/json -f payload.json
```

**Subscribe**

```
mqtt sub -h orgId.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com -p 443 -l wss -i a:orgId:default_mobile -u API-key -P 'API-token' --ca messaging.pem -t iot-2/type/mobile/id/default_mobile/evt/live/fmt/json
```

For subscription, I have created API keys and am using the same. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the subscription topic seems to be incorrect. If your device is publishing in

iot-2/evt/data/fmt/json

then you should subscribe to

iot-2/type/mobile/id/default_mobile/evt/data/fmt/json

Note: mind **data** instead of **live**

Comment: The device publishes to `iot-2/evt/data/fmt/json` which is subscribed to by IBM IoT input node. The IBM IoT input node publishes to an Output node where event type is set to `live`. My aim is to subscribe to messages as published by the Output node _over wss_.

Comment: would it be possible to send the configuration of the node-red iot output node to have a look?

Comment: When I tried pasting the JSON of the entire flow at pastebin.org, the spam detector stopped me! So, here is node alone. `[{"id":"d9d6d027.eb598","type":"ibmiot out","z":"4dd997f2.a81f","authentication":"boundService","apiKey":"","outputType":"evt","deviceId":"default_mobile","deviceType":"mobile","eventCommandType":"live","format":"json","data":"LiveStatus","qos":0,"name":"Application","service":"registered","x":290,"y":300,"wires":[]}]` Wire an IBM IoT input node to it. Publish to Input node via `mosquitto_pub` and try receiving data from IBM IoT output node through `mqtt sub`.

Comment: one question, do you see events coming from the IoT out node? You can wire a debug node and check.

Comment: Where do I wire the Debug node to on an _out_ node? BTW, I realised that, if I wire the input node to output node directly then, the `msg.` attributes (in the input node) will override the ones set in the Output node. I am now using a function node in between to set the relevant `msg.` attributes. No luck, yet.

Comment: my mistake here, meant IoT in. I want to make sure you see events arriving in nodered from mosquitto_pub

Comment: Yes; that is confirmed. Messages are received in Input node.

Comment: then node red side seems to be fine. Can you add v option to the mqtt client and see what is saying?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176414/discussion-between-cogitoergosum-and-idan).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @idan this problem is now resolved!

1. Devices (beginning with a `d:`) can subscribe to `iot-2/cmd` topic strings only.
2. I had wired the input node to output node directly. Therefore, all the settings in the output node were being overridden with `msg.` attributes. So, I put in a function node that sets the `msg.` attributes. Alternatively (as suggested by @idan), the function node can have a single line as `msg=msg.payload` so that the attributes in the node are not overridden.

Comment: If problem is resolved, then it would be good to accept the best answer.